# Flask-Caching in Azure App Service , which uses gunicorn server

Tags: flask, gunicorn, wsgi, azure-app-service-envrmnt, flask-caching

below code is work absolutely fine , when i am using development server in my local machine , but when i tried to deploy this to azure app service it is not working . In Azure App service gunicorn is the server that we are using .

does Flask-Caching support gunicorn server ?

or is there way around to do this

```
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import Flask

config = {
 "DEBUG": True,          # some Flask specific configs
 "CACHE_TYPE": "filesystem", # Flask-Caching related configs
 "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 3600
  }

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)


@app.route('/getdata/<a>/<b>')
@cache.memoize(3600)
def getdata_(a,b):
    result = "some function which output result"
    return result
```

Comment: Can you expand on: `it is not working`.  What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @v25 , in my local system after caching the time is reduced from 19 second to approx 450 ms , but from appservice there is no change in the time

Comment: i have changed the Cache_TYPE from simple to filesystem , as simple is used only for development server

Comment: Did changing to 'filesystem' resolve this issue?